# Is it possible to find location by iPhone device ID?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mapkit

I wanted to know, is it posisble to get location(latitude, longitude) by device ID on iPhone? for example, if i want to make an iPhone app that finds friends with in university campus, I have my friend's device IDs but not their location. Is it really possible? I am sorry for my ignorance but please guide me.

Thanks,
Regards,
Ainee

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't obtain the location of your friends' iPhones with any standard iOS API. To do something like that, you should have a server component as well, and have you app report the location to it. Then you should be able to query the server about the location of any user that is running the app.

Comment: Thanks a lot. i had the same solution in my mind that we periodically send GPRS location to the server and then we can query server. But my client is still of the view that there are apps like "find my friend" that use device id to find device location.